# Good book for Crystal Reports?

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I'm new to Crystal Reports and was interested in finding out what books would be most helpful.  I'm planning on using the Designer as well as integrating Crystal Reports with a .NET C# application.

Anybody have any idea which are the best books for this purpose?

Comment: Crystal Reports is one of those things, where you learn as you develop.  Unlike programming languages and complicated deep frameworks, Crystal Reports is simply a fancy view to the database.  If you know SQL, and spend time learning the basics of CR and manipulating and aggregating the data returned, you'll learn in no time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some suggestions:

Crystal Reports 2008: The Complete Reference (Osborne Complete Reference Series):
[http://www.amazon.com/Crystal-Reports-2008-Complete-Reference/dp/0071590986/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1246629337&sr=8-5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071590986)

Crystal Reports 10: The Complete Reference (Complete Reference Series):
[http://www.amazon.com/Crystal-Reports-10-Complete-Reference/dp/0072231661/ref=sr_1_26?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1246629400&sr=8-26](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072231661)

Professional Crystal Reports for Visual Studio .NET, 2nd Edition:
[http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Crystal-Reports-Visual-Studio/dp/0764557300/ref=sr_1_34?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1246629455&sr=8-34](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764557300)

All come highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

**Crystal Reports .NET Programming**

*By **Brian Bischof***

I think this is a nice one

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Reports Encyclopedia   by Brian Bischof